# Cannot access input value in React form

Tags: reactjs

In order to learn [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_%28JavaScript_library%29) I decided to make a little Todo application by myself using information from the official tutorial.

I made a little form to submit a new task, but in my component, I can't access the value of the refs. It shows every time undefined when I'm trying to access its value via:

```
this.refs.task.value
```

Here's the component:

```js
var TodoForm = React.createClass({

    handleSubmit: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var task = this.refs.task.value;
        alert(task);
        this.refs.task.value = '';
        return;
    },

    render: function(){
        return (
            <ul className="list-group">
                <li className="list-group-item">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <input ref="task" className="form-control" type="text" placeholder="ajouter une tache"  />
                            <input type="submit" className="btn btn-default" value="envoyer" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
});
```

I added the small alert to control the value of the task variable, and it shows undefined.

What is wrong with that code?

Comment: It seem like since React 0.14, this.refs.task.value will be valid for build-in component. https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/10/07/react-v0.14.html#dom-node-refs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.refs.task` is a React reference pointing to an element. It doesn't store the elements value inside of itself. You need to pull out the DOM node and then get the value:

```
this.refs.task.findDOMNode().value
```

Comment: @JonasBarenfeld sure thing! when you are able if you could mark the answer as accepted I would greatly appreciate it :D

Comment: Sure thing, quick update, just saw that getDOMNode() has been depecrated so i'm using findDOMNode()

Answer (score 0):

If anything, dont set value directly to DOM element.`this.refs.task.value = '';`

Also, it is better aproach to hang the ref on your form, and use native methods. So you can do `<form ref="myForm">` and then just access its elements `this.refs.myForm.inputName.value` where `inpuName` is name of the field. Henc you are not using attribute name, you should.